# Why the first character is skipped in 2nd iterations onwards

Tags: getline

**Code part:**

```
 int t; 
    cout<<"Enter a no."; 
    cin>>t;

    while(t--){
    cout<<"Enter a string :"<<endl;

    string str;
    cin.ignore();

    getline(cin,str);
    cout<<"You entered :"<<str<<endl<<endl;
}
```

[**Output**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mz8jL.png)

```
Enter a no. 3
Enter a string :
It is working
You entered :It is working

Enter a string :
It is working
You entered :t is working

Enter a string :
It is working 
You entered :t is working
```

Why the first character is skipped in 2nd iterations onward. Any help will be welcomed.

Comment: If I am removing cin.ignore() then input is not taken correctly, so what should I do to take input in each iterations .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `cin>>t;` reads a number from the user. Because the user has to hit enter after the number, you need the `cin.ignore()` to ignore the newline. However, in the loop, you use `getline`, which reads an entire line. There is nothing to ignore since you've read the entire line. So you need to move the `cin.ignore()` to *before* the loop.

Personally, I prefer to *always* read lines from the user since that's what I expect the user to enter.